# XML - dual URIs in a single xmlns definition, is it valid?

Tags: python, xml, xml-namespaces, elementtree

I have some XML that has an xmlns declaration as follows:

```
<dc:record xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mods="http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3 http://www.loc.gov/standards/mods/v3/mods-3-0.xsd">
```

This line seems to be tripping the eTree XML parser in Python:

```
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: xmlns:mods: 'http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3 http://www.loc.gov/standards/mods/v3/mods-3-0.xsd' is not a valid URI, line 6, column 63
```

If I remove one of the two URIs found in the xmlns:mods declaration, it parses fine.

So, knowing that the xmlns element is there to aid human parsing, and is not meant to specifically be deferenced, is this a genuine constraint on XML (to have a single URI in a xmlns namespace declaration), or is it an overzealous enforcement by the lxml etree parser?

Comment: A nitpick: `xmlns` is not meant for humans--it's the actual namespace, and a namespace *must* be a URI (deferenceable or not). It's the *prefix* that is for humans.

Comment: @FrancisAvila Ahh, very good, thank you. Consider my nit, picked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that lxml.etree is doing the right thing here.

According to [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml-names11-20060816/), a namespace declaration attribute must have a value that is "either an [IRI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_Resource_Identifier) reference — the namespace name identifying the namespace — or an empty string"

Your example has the attribute value `"http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3 http://www.loc.gov/standards/mods/v3/mods-3-0.xsd"`, which is not a valid IRI (colon in the wrong place, e.g.)

Comment: I tend to agree. I appreciate your thoughts. Its always useful to get an outside / expert view on these things. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The question of whether or not a namespace name MUST be a valid URI is a vexed one. Certainly what you have here is wrong; but whether your parser is "overzealous" is another matter.

The namespaces 1.1 spec says in section 8, "a processor must report violations of namespace well-formedness, with the exception that it is not required to check that namespace names are legal IRIs".

In practice, most parsers don't do this check, and once a majority of software products are lenient about enforcing a provision in a spec, software that does enforce it starts to become unpopular with users.

Comment: An excellent answer, thank you. I guess in that regard, both are correct. The parser is doing its job, and the declaration (formedness of the IRI) is conforming to common convention.